# osx - touchesBegan without end nor cancel

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

the problem is I am working with a trackpad on OS X 10.11. To reproduce my problem, it's enough to create simple Cocoa Application and add the code below to ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES];
}

-(void) touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesBeganWithEvent");
}

-(void) touchesCancelledWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesCancelledWithEvent");
}

-(void) touchesEndedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesEndedWithEvent");
}
```

After launch just do a 3 or 4 finger swipe to change desktop, you will see 2 or 3 messages: touchesBeganWithEvent. That's it. I need to track down touches, but app will fill with touches that just began and never ended.

Why touches aren't canceled or ended? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: From documentation, Multiple touches are disabled by default. In order to receive multiple touch events you must set the a multipleTouchEnabled property of the corresponding view instance to YES.

Comment: As far as I know it's iOS property, not OS X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems this is some sort of weird behavior, the only way I see is to get all active touches in `touchesBeganWithEvent:` and compare to your stored ones to remove canceled ones.

```
- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *) theEvent
{
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseAny inView:nil];
    NSMutableArray* touchesToRemove = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

    for (NSTouch* storedTouch in storedTouches) {
        for (NSTouch* touch in touches) {
             if ([[touch identity] isEqual:[storedTouch identity]])
                 [touchesToRemove addObject:storedTouch];
        }
    }

    for (NSTouch* touch in touchesToRemove) {
        [storedTouches removeObject:touch];
    }

    // process new touches as always
}
```

Some pseudocode to show the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but I assume that your app gets inactive at this point as you are switching to a different Desktop.

Check the `applicationDidResignActive` method, there you can do your touch cancellation if swipes were involved in changing to another application.

Comment: That's what I am doing already, the problem is when user swipes to the side where no screen is present, screen makes a wobbly animation, app doesn't get switched, no events I am tracking come

Comment: Something I often do while debugging is setting up a NSNotificationCenter observer without name or object. This way I get all notifications. Print their names, maybe something in there helps you.

Comment: Sadly there are no notification at that point. The only ones I am spammed with are NSApplicationWillUpdateNotification, NSWindowDidUpdateNotification, NSApplicationDidUpdateNotification. And according to docs they don't have any userInfo properties.